# How to determine salaries greater than the average salary

Tags: sql

Assume I have the following table

```
id  name city   salary  dept
```

and I want to select all salaries which are greater than the average salary

Comment: You just HAVE TO say something more.. what is it. a DataBase table or what?

Comment: I thinks its criminal to mark this 'algorithm'

Answer (score 29):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT salary WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM *)
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming it's mysql, only the below two work. (I used a temp table so the names are different from yours)

```
select * from b  where ref > (select avg(ref) from b);
select * from b  having ref > (select avg(ref) from b);
```

This doesn't - `select * from b  having ref > avg(ref);`

Some queries I tried -

```
mysql> select * from b;
+------+------------+------+
| id   | d2         | ref  |
+------+------------+------+
|  300 | 2010-12-12 |    3 |
|  300 | 2011-12-12 |    2 |
|  300 | 2012-12-12 |    1 |
|  400 | 2011-12-12 |    1 |
+------+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from b  having ref > avg(ref);
+------+------------+------+
| id   | d2         | ref  |
+------+------------+------+
|  300 | 2010-12-12 |    3 |
+------+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from b  having ref > (select avg(ref) from b);
+------+------------+------+
| id   | d2         | ref  |
+------+------------+------+
|  300 | 2010-12-12 |    3 |
|  300 | 2011-12-12 |    2 |
+------+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from b  where ref > (select avg(ref) from b);
+------+------------+------+
| id   | d2         | ref  |
+------+------------+------+
|  300 | 2010-12-12 |    3 |
|  300 | 2011-12-12 |    2 |
+------+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *,avg(ref) from b  having ref > avg(ref);
+------+------------+------+----------+
| id   | d2         | ref  | avg(ref) |
+------+------------+------+----------+
|  300 | 2010-12-12 |    3 |   1.7500 |
+------+------------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

If windowed aggregate functions are supported:

```
SELECT Salary
FROM (
  SELECT
    Salary,
    AVG(Salary) OVER () AS AvgSalary
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE Salary > AvgSalary
```

Comment: The most efficient answer, queries the table only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
select empno,e.deptno,sal 
  from emp e, ( select deptno,avg(sal) avsal 
                  from emp 
              group by deptno
              ) a 
 where e.sal > a.avsal 
   and e.deptno = a.deptno;
```

Comment: get a salary for a employee who is getting morethan the avg salary from Department

Answer (score 1):

its really easy just use following short command given below

```
SELECT *FROM table_name WHERE salary > avg(select salary from table_name)
```

HOPE YOU GET IT :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the name of table is **Employee(id, name, city, salary)**

```
select salary from Employee where salary > (select ava(salary) from employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming emp is the name of the table, which has department id as `dept_id`*

1. Query results shows all employees details whose salary is greater than the average salary of that department. (Department Wise)

(Group by department)

```
select e1.* from emp e1  inner join (select avg(sal) avg_sal,dept_id from emp group by
dept_id) as e2 on e1.dept_id=e2.dept_id and e1.sal>e2.avg_sal
```

2. Query results shows all employees details whose salary is greater than average salary.

   ```
   select * from emp where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Following shall work for you.

```
SELECT salary FROM table_name WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.employee_id, e.department_id, e.salary from employees e
where salary > (
select  avg(salary)
from employees d where e.department_id =d.department_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(SALARY) from table_name);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).