# Query to Identify Above Average Sales for Company

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find the employees who have sales figures that are above the average sales totals for a particular company. I am using Microsoft SQL Server, and here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Name,
        SalesTotal as Sales,
        AVG(SalesTotal) as MeanSales
    FROM
        Employees
    GROUP BY
        Name
        SalesTotal
    ) nested
WHERE Sales > MeanSales
```

However, my query returns nothing. Is this the correct way to write something like this? What could I do to simplify things?

Comment: Could you try putting the average (MeanSales) in a variable and querying it before running the actual query?

Comment: The question is not clear.  Do you want anyone in any company that is bigger than the average of a particular company?  Do you only want to consider employees of one particular company?  Do you only want to consider employees against their own company?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine salaries greater than the average salary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403810/how-to-determine-salaries-greater-than-the-average-salary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 1 row for each employee in the table then use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which returns the average:

```
SELECT Name, SalesTotal AS Sales
FROM Employees        
WHERE SalesTotal > (SELECT AVG(SalesTotal) FROM Employees)
```

Comment: Subquery is probably going to be less efficient than a windowed aggregate

Comment: @Charlieface a subquery that the optimizer will execute only once is a better choice than window functions.

Answer (score 2):

The `AVG` of a single scalar value is going to be the single scalar value, and a scalar value cannot be greater than itself. You want a windowed aggregate here:

```sql
--I prefer CTEs
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           SalesTotal,
           AVG(SalesTotal) OVER () AS AvgTotal
    FROM dbo.Employees)
SELECT [Name],
       SalesTotal
FROM CTE
WHERE SalesTotal > AvgTotal;
```