# list of student name who obtains above than class average marks:

Tags: mysql, sql

**Hi All**,
Today I have gone through a interview in which interviewer asked me this question ,please help me to solve this problem.
There is **`student`** table which is having **`Student_id, student_name, Student_class, marks`**.

So need to write a SQL query to fetch all student records who scored more than class average.
I have tried a lot ,I have used to **`ROW_NUMBER()`** function for min and Max marks by each class student but couldn't find the solution for **`avg()`**.

`SELECT * FROM (Select *,Row_Number() OVER (Partition By Class Order By Marks desc) As rn From Students) where rn=1`

[image]

Comment: I have used below query to find the max and min .                                                        SELECT * FROM (Select *,Row_Number() OVER (Partition By Class Order By Marks desc) As rn From Students)
where rn=1

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. You can use [edit] to add the info to your question.

Comment: Do https://stackoverflow.com/a/6403850/2681662 solve your problem?

Comment: I can downvote if someone writes "I have total 6 Years of experience in SQL Server" and is not capable of doing such a basic SQL query...   Please share more SQL code you tried... (in the question, and not in the comments)  Also share data as TEXT, not as [IMAGES](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Is Stack Overflow a code writing service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service)

Comment: Hi @AjeetVerma: Please check the below query in answer section. Hope It'll meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First class wise average marks are calculated inside subquery and JOINS it with student table for only those students info where class wise average marks are greater than students marks.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT s.student_id
     , s.student_name
     , s.student_class
     , s.marks
FROM student s
INNER JOIN (SELECT student_class
                 , AVG(marks) avg_marks
            FROM student
            GROUP BY student_class ) c
        ON s.student_class = c.student_class
       AND s.marks > c.avg_marks
ORDER BY s.student_id;
```

Please check from URL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17f863/3

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase. I've added explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This can also work, a little simpler, but maybe not the best from performance point of view:

```
SELECT      student.*
FROM        student
JOIN        student s2 ON student.Student_class = s2.Student_class
GROUP BY    student.Student_id
HAVING      student.marks > AVG(s2.marks)
```

It joins the class average to every student row and groups for student, filtering only the rows where mark is above class average.

Assuming that you will need average by classes at some other points as well, you can consider creating a view to show averages:

```
CREATE VIEW class_average AS
    SELECT  Student_class AS class,
            AVG(marks) AS average 
    FROM    student
    GROUP BY Student_class
```

And they the query to select above average students goes like:

```
SELECT      student.*
FROM        student
JOIN        class_average ON
                student.Student_class = class_average.class AND
                student.marks > class_average.average
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Modified solution)

`SELECT S1.*
FROM Student S1
WHERE marks > (SELECT AVG(marks) FROM Student S2 WHERE S1.Student_class = S2.Student_class)`

The above solution compare each marks against the average mark in specific class.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This solution uses global average, not average by class. The result is only the same because of the data, accidentally.

Comment: Sure, the first solution will not work because i missed word "class average". I think the modified solution will work well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I will answer with a 'standard' way to solve this:

If you have this:

```
SELECT i FROM integers WHERE i<10;
```

with output:

```
i
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Then you can do:

```
select i%3,avg(i)  X 
from integers 
where i<10 
group by i%3 ;
```

which will output:

```
            X
----------- -----------
0           6
1           4
2           5
```

Now, back to the question, if you only want rows with an average above 4:

```
select i%3,avg(i)  X 
from integers 
where i<10 
group by i%3 
having avg(i)>4;
```

output:

```
            X
----------- -----------
0           6
2           5
```